# Do I need 2 public IPs for my hosting?

Tags: ip, web-hosting, nameserver

Is it necessary to have 2 public IPs for a simple-domain hosting?

I want to host my own website in my school but I don't know if I can without 2 IPs, I have only one...

For exemple, may this work:

```
ns1.exemple.com => 70.10.10.10
ns2.exemple.com => 70.10.10.10
```

Or I very need:

```
ns1.exemple.com => 70.10.10.10
ns2.exemple.com => 70.10.10.11
```

Comment: There's an [RFC for that](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2182).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you talking about web hosting, or [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)?  These are two separate services.

For DNS you really should have at least two machines.  They wll back up each other for redundancy.  However,  unless you very large, and running many domains there is almost no reason to try running your own DNS server.  Almost all registrars will host the DNS for you for free.

For web hosting, you only need a single ip address.  In fact, with [Virtual Hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) you can host any number of sites.

Alternatively, you could pay for a [web hosting service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service). (There are tons of these on the Internet)  They can manage your DNS for you (if you like) and provide space for your website on their servers with a reliable Internet connection.

Comment: +1, I hadn't even considered OP may have been asking about configuring name servers, in addition to a web server.

Comment: Thanks. The hostnames ns1/ns2... are funny.  I thought the OP might be confused.

Comment: I don't like web hosting service... We cannot host thing that we want! If I want my Active Directory on the same server as my hosting, I can't with a WHS!

Comment: The are many providers who provide backup DNS hosts.  Ideally you want your DNS hosts at geographically separate locations.